# Linq Intersect with partial match

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get 'Intersect' to return true for a partial word match in a Linq query in? I need a `.Contains() .Intersect()` hybrid of sorts.

```
 List<string> sParams = new List<string>(){"SAND", "PURPLE"};

 //One of my Prices has the color "Sanddust"
 Prices.Where(x => x.Color.ToUpper().Split(null).Intersect(sParams).Any());
```

The above query only returns exact string match intersects, but I need to to return true as the string "SANDDUST" contains "SAND".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need intersect? Just use an Any Contains.

```
Prices.Where(x => sParams.Any(s => x.Color.ToUpper().Contains(s)));
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I am not sure why I felt like I needed to split both strings and compare??? One of those days.

Comment: Do you need to do case? If so check out this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923158/c-sharp-contains-part-of-string

Answer (score 1):

```
Prices.Where(x => sParams.Any(s=> x.Color.ToUpper().Contains(s));
```

Comment: Also if you want to answer questions, its better if you actually describe your solution, how it works, and any other relevant information